# how to query basic thing on firebase through simulator

Tags: firebase

I just set up my hello world firebase app. I saw there is a simulator tool on firebase's dashboard and I want to use it simply like,

https://boiling-inferno-1234.firebaseio.com/boiling-inferno-1234/Cat

I clicked "Simulate Read" and there is the output,

```
Attempt to read /boiling-inferno-1234/Cat with auth=null
Default rules.  Read allowed.
```

but no actual data.

I chose "unauthenticated" method and I also did have any security constraints.

My data is like,

```
boiling-inferno-1234  
 Cat: "Blue"
 Elephan: "White"
 Fly: "Yellow"
 Mouse: "Black"
```

What could be possibly wrong?

Comment: The simulator is used to test your Firebase Rules, not to query your data. You can view your data in the Data icon link. See the note on the simulator page. To work with and query your data you will need to code up an app/write some java etc - there's really good examples and getting started info on the site. Read up and write some code!

Comment: Sounds like an answer Jay. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simulator is used to test your Firebase Rules, not to query your data.

You can view your data in the Data icon link. See the note on the simulator page regarding what it does.

To work with and query your data you will need to code up an app/write some java etc - there's really good examples in a variety of languages as well as getting started info on the Firebase website.

Read up and write some code!